# Filtering Punctuation from an Array (what is the exclamation '!' doing?)

Tags: javascript

In example 1, the exclamation (!) is at the start of the punctuation array and does not get logged.

```
let lettersArray = ['h','i','!','$','%','#','"']

let punctuation = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~';
let filterPunc = lettersArray.filter((letter) => punctuation.indexOf(letter) > 0 )
console.log(filterPunc);
// ['$', '%', '#']
```

In example 2, the exclamation is somewhere else in the punctuation array and now gets logged.

```
let punctuation1 = '"#$%&!\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~';
let filterPunc1 = lettersArray.filter((letter) => punctuation1.indexOf(letter) > 0 )
console.log(filterPunc1);
// ['!', '$', '%', '#']
```

I believe it's being interpreted as a logical-not-operator but I'm unsure why since I would assume the quotation marks would make it a string.

Comment: The exclamation isn't being interpreted any differently, your condition is just wrong. Same thing would happen with any other character that's first in the string (" in the second example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `punctuation.indexOf(letter) > 0` you shall use `punctuation.indexOf(letter) >= 0` or better `punctuation.includes(letter)`.

If you use `>` instead of `>=` the first element which has index 0 would get excluded.
And nevertheless `indexOf` returns `-1` for non existing elements, not `0`.

Comment: Or use `punctuation.includes(letter)`